# sql server - Procedure that checks if row values from INSERT already exist in database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I need to create procedure that doesn't allow insertion of duplicate values and procedure has to check if column "zipcode" is in valid format (5 digits only).

I didn't find a proper solution yet and that's why I'm writing this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** I know about unique constraints, but I'm doing assignment for job recruitment and I HAVE TO implement it via procedure.

Btw is there a alternative in MS SQL to keyword **new** from MySQL? I need that to do what I want I believe...

Comment: You should probably do this via constraints rather than a stored procedure. e.g. make the column UNIQUE and add a check constraint

Comment: If you are asking a question it is considered best practice to show us what you have tried, what errors you have encountered and any table structures that you have.

Comment: I edited my question.

Anyway,  I know about unique constraints, but I'm doing assignment for job recruitment and I HAVE TO implement it via procedure. 

I don't know how to get values from INSERT to check if there already exist any.. My table is pretty much simple.. For example, CREATE TABLE (dataId int primary key, name varchar(20), surname varchar(20), zipcode varchar(6), city varchar(20), phone varchar(20);

Comment: You'll probably be better off passing on the job until you can handle this without help.  Its better to start at an entry level job and work your way up, then get fired from an advanced job because you don't have enough knowledge.

Comment: I'm applying as junior developer and they are aware I didn't work in ASP.NET MVC + MS SQL before. Basically they are just trying to see how much time I need to learn something new to me.

Comment: Try reading documentation at MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms345415.aspx and the examples at the end of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: The trouble with using a stored procedure to try and prevent duplicates is that it isn't guaranteed to prevent duplicates unless you use a very restrictive transaction isolation level (pessimistic concurrency). There's a hint for you, now try finding out more about this yourself it will stand you in good stead.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion on asking questions about homework http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thank you @Steve, I appreciate your help and I believe I will find my way through!

Answer (score 0):

Hi for check you can use something like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_your_table CHECK (zipcode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

for duplicate use UNIQUE

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not allowed to use constraints. I have to implement it via procedure, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using a stored procedure is that if any user has UPDATE permissions on the table they can bypass your checking and add invalid and duplicate data, you should therefore use table constraints on the table to handle this or a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE #Zip
(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY Identity,
    [ZIPCode] VARCHAR(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CK_ZIPCode CHECK ( [ZIPCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' ),
    Place VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

Now if you run the following inserts:

```
Insert into #Zip VALUES ('12345', 'MyPlace')
Insert into #Zip VALUES ('12345', 'MyPlace2')
Insert into #Zip VALUES ('A2345', 'MyPlace3')
Insert into #Zip VALUES ('13345', 'MyPlace4')
```

The first one succeeds,
the second fails with

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

the third fails with:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "CK_ZIPCode".

and the 4th succeeds.

For any more complex checking you should use a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Edited my post. The thing is I have to use procedure.